# Is there an alternative method to unlocking story-mode characters?

Tags: mortal-kombat-9

One of the things I do at my office is murder everyone in MK9. It would be best if I had the maximal amount of characters with which to exact vengeance on my coworkers.

However, while we can find 15 minutes for a few quick rounds, playing through the story mode to unlock cyber Sub-Zero and Quan-Chi is not really something we have time for. Is there any sort of cheat I can employ to unlock both of them in a different manner?

It's worth pointing out that we hava an XBOX360 at the office, so I'm looking for a solution that would work on that platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're up for spending the money (MK9 should be pretty cheap by now), you could get the komplete edition, which comes with Cyber Sub-Zero and Quan Chi already unlocked, as well as all the other DLC characters (Rain, Skarlet, Freddy Krueger, Kenshi).
It's $16 from Amazon

Comment: I suppose cash is the only viable option. Are you sure about Cyber Sub-Zero and Quan Chi, though? I have the Komplete edition on my PC at home and I still had to unlock those two... I think.

Comment: I bought the komplete edition on PC (on Steam) and 360 and both times all characters were unlocked.

Comment: Then I must not have been paying attention before playing through story mode anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use another saved data file.  For example, you could try [this file](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/961031-mortal-kombat/saves).

Comment: That would have been a terrific solution if we had a PS3 at the office. Definitely information I should add to the question.